# Java / Google Calendar, Contacts / OAuth 2.0 / must sign me again

Tags: java, maven, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api

I’m trying to write a Java daemon who works with Google calendar and Google contacts. Problem : regulary, I must delete my credential file from filesystem and I have to identify myself again through the web page provided by my local Jetty server.

My Maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and my Credential factory:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import xxx.io.ResourceOrFileAccessor;

public class GoogleConnectivityHelper
{
    private static final Logger             LOGGER                  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleConnectivityHelper.class);

    public static final String              DEFAULT_CONTACTS_FEED   = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
    public static final Collection<String>  DEFAULT_CONTACTS_SCOPE  = Collections.singleton(DEFAULT_CONTACTS_FEED);

    public static final String              DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET   = "/client_secret.json";

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport            httpTransport;

    static
    {
        try
        {
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOGGER.error("", e);
        }
    }

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private GoogleConnectivityHelper()
    {}

    public static Credential authorize(Collection<String> scopes, String clientSecret) throws IOException
    {
        return authorize(scopes, clientSecret, (File) null);
    }

    public static Credential authorize(Collection<String> scopes, String clientSecret, String dataStorePath) throws IOException
    {
        if (dataStorePath == null) return authorize(scopes, clientSecret);
        return authorize(scopes, clientSecret, new File(dataStorePath));
    }

    public static Credential authorize(Collection<String> scopes, String clientSecret, File dataStorePath) throws IOException
    {
        if (dataStorePath == null) dataStorePath = new File(".");

        // load client secrets
        LOGGER.debug("Credential creation with clientSecret={} and dataStorePath={}", clientSecret, dataStorePath.getAbsolutePath());
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(ResourceOrFileAccessor.getAsStream(clientSecret)));
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter") || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter "))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // initialize the data store factory
        FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(dataStorePath);

        // initialize the transport

        // set up authorization code flow
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

    public static HttpTransport getHttpTransport()
    {
        return httpTransport;
    }

}
```

Does anyone have a working example? Or maybe corrected my mistake?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you checked out the [Google Identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/) as well as [Contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en), [Calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) APIs? The java client library can be useful to what you want to develop.